Error occurred: TypeError: Blob.encode[lamports] requires (length 8) Uint8Array as src
My code

async function sendSolanaBalance(privateKeyBase58: string, recipientAddress: string) {
try {
const privateKeyBytes = bs58.decode(privateKeyBase58);
const senderKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(privateKeyBytes);

    while (true) {
        const senderPublicKey = senderKeypair.publicKey;
        const senderAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(senderPublicKey);

        if (!senderAccountInfo) {
            console.error("Sender account not found.");
            return;
        }

        const senderBalance = senderAccountInfo.lamports;
        const  whattosend = senderBalance- 1000000

        if (senderBalance === 0) {
            console.error("Sender account balance is zero.");
            return;
        }

        const transaction = new Transaction().add(
            SystemProgram.transfer({
                fromPubkey: senderPublicKey,
                toPubkey: new PublicKey(recipientAddress),
                lamports: whattosend, // Use higher lamports for a higher fee
            })
        );

        // Sign transaction
        transaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getRecentBlockhash()).blockhash;
        transaction.sign(senderKeypair);

        // Send transaction
        const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction.serialize());
        console.log("Transaction sent. Signature:", signature);

        // Wait for the specified interval before sending the next transaction
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occurred:", error);
}

}
// Function to pause execution for the specified time
function sleep(ms: number) {
return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
and send me error

Error occurred: TypeError: Blob.encode[lamports] requires (length 8) Uint8Array as src
at Blob.encode (c:\Users\Home\Desktop\Solana transfers\node_modules@solana\buffer-layout\src\Layout.ts:2290:13)
at Blob.bigIntLayout.encode (c:\Users\Home\Desktop\Solana transfers\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\utils\bigint.ts:31:14)
at Structure.encode (c:\Users\Home\Desktop\Solana transfers\node_modules@solana\buffer-layout\src\Layout.ts:1205:26)
at encodeData (c:\Users\Home\Desktop\Solana transfers\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\instruction.ts:32:15)
at Function.transfer (c:\Users\Home\Desktop\Solana transfers\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\programs\system.ts:796:14)
at sendSolanaBalance (c:\Users\Home\Desktop\Solana transfers\send.ts:40:31)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


This is a very strange error... I wonder if there's an issue of a negative number being sent in. Can you check that whattosend is positive?
